# iOS SDK standard collections

Tags: objective-c, collections

I'm new to objective-c. I can't find such classed as NSStack, NSList and so on. But i need containers to write the application. The only containers i've found are NSArray and NSMutableArray. I know that i can use STL containers, but i'm not sure it's the best way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For lists, you can use `NSArray`, `NSMutableArray`. For dictionary/hashmap, you can use `NSDictionary`, `NSHashMap`. For sets, you can use `NSSet`, `NSMutableSet`.

[Here's](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i) Apple documentation on collections.

As you previously mentioned, you can also use C or C++ standard libraries, but do keep in mind that for storing Objective-C classes, it will be more convenient to use Objective-C native collections.